# LaTex or ConTeXt for a new user?

Tags: context

I'm just starting out with LaTeX.

Would I be better off learning ConTeXt instead?

Which of the two is better for a beginner - assuming I do want to tweak the formatting occasionally?

Comment: Answers might be more informative if you describe what types of documents you hope to write in LaTeX or ConTeXt.  (Eventually, it will be all types, of course, but your initial reasons/goals/aspirations deserve consideration in the short term.)

Comment: In particular, are you writing papers you might want to submit to journals or publishers at some point? Do you need to format academic work according to institutional requirements (e.g. a thesis)?

Comment: Some related questions: [Persuade me to write my thesis in ConTeXt, or not](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46028) and [Why should I be interested in ConTeXt?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4987) and [I am new to TeX. Should I use LaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42628). This last one is quite possibly a duplicate.