# Minimal TeXLive installation

Tags: texlive, installing, docker, continuous-integration

I'm building a script for a CI to get a docker image with minimal distribution of Texlive possible, I specifically want to avoid pulling 5 Gb of `texlive-full` everytime I need this docker image.

Right now I see this script as

1. install `texlive-something`
2. `tlmgr install latexmk`
3. `tlmgr install texliveonfly`
4. `texliveonfly -c latexmk -a "-pdf -f -synctex=0" myFile.tex` (install missing tex packages and compile with `latexmk`)
5. deploy results and cache the tex-related part of the image.

Which package should I chose for `texlive-something` so that these steps work? Thanks in advance.

**edit**

It seems that the word *minimal* can lead to some confusion. In this case it means (for a package)

1. Has a set of binaries (`pdflatex`, `tlmgr`, `bibtex`/`biber`, `perl`, I might be missing something) that would allow me to compile an empty document. Should I need some other binaries, I'm ok with adding this dependencies by hand
2. Contains a minimal set of LaTeX packages so that an empty document would compile. If I understand correctly, most other packages will be handled by `texliveonfly` (barring some esoteric cases, of course, but that can be handled manually, too).

In other words, minimal in terms of total disk space under the hypothesis that an empty document compiles using the instruments I mentioned.

Comment: You can say that "minimal" is texlive with nothing more... And it is not even minimal . Anything more is a matter of taste and opinion based... But I gave an answer by my experience with the packages that I always have to install (math is a mast for me anyway... but texlive users love math and if not... have to)

Comment: I also think that in different linux distros  the packages are not exactly the same... (Just noticing for anyone who will see this question) [But this could be because of different texlive releases... not sure... Just happened to me before]

Comment: This heavily depends on what you want to use the installation for.

Comment: @samcarter could you elaborate?

Comment: You are talking about empty files (I suppose you mean "hello world" latex files)... and as far as I know just the package `texlive` is enough (and much more than enough for this)

Comment: Interesting setups can be investigated at https://github.com/adinriv/docker-texlive. Containing a) minimal texlive, b) basic texlive, and c) a full set of other helpers (inkscape, ...)

Comment: You seem to be mixing installation methods. While you might be able to do this in a limited way, it isn't guaranteed and may not be supported at all. If you're installing a package called `texlive-<something>`, you are presumably using a Linux distro's package manager to do so. But then you are using `tlmgr` to install other stuff. The distro may provide a modified `tlmgr` which installs stuff, but it would be better by far to stick to packages designed to work together. But maybe this is required for `texliveonfly` or something.  Or I'm just confused.

Comment: @cfr The distro may indeed provide a modified version of `tlmgr`. However, my experience with `textlive` on ubuntu can be summed as "forget about `texlive` from ubuntu's package manager, grab its latest version from tug.org and use its `tlmgr`"

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Then I don't understand the `texlive-<something>`. I assumed that was a distro package name. Apparently not.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Can you share your Docker file? I will need it to customize it, such as to build the backend of a website.

Comment: @projetmbc hi! I am on vacation without access to a laptop. If you still need my Docker image mid-January, feel free to ping me) I'll try to remember to open-source it nonetheless

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Ok. I will to do that.

Comment: @projetmbc if you are still interested: https://github.com/ShrykeWindgrace/TeXLive-CI-minimal

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Yes I am. Thanks for sharing...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Installing texlive from TUG (https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) you can have a minimal latex installation with 76 MB by selecting:

- the `basic` scheme

[image]

- not installing documentation and source

[image]

Comment: Hm, that's interesting, thank you. I'll try to run the installation with this profile.

Comment: This is the best answer. Always install TeXLive from official source. The various package managers (apt-get, homebrew, etc) may not have packaged the latest TeXLive, or worse, may have incorrect packaging. This has my upvote.

Comment: One problem though: when I followed the official doc to get the minimal-texlive installed, `tlmgr` is missing from the command-line. (This is with Windows 10 under WSL2, Pengwin distro. I have restarted the machine.)

Comment: @llinfeng somehow it doesn't add the exec to `PATH`. I'm using Lubuntu, that's strange.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa I recall having installed `tlmgr` manually afterward.

Comment: @llinfeng I reinstalled and found out that you have to select that `create symlinks in standard directories` option. Why is it not the default option?

Answer (score 8):

I use [TinyTeX](https://yihui.name/tinytex/), it was developed for [R](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) but works nicely for other purposes.

Management is done by command-line using tlmgr as usual, and the profile file is easy to understand and adjust:

> TinyTeX is a custom (and probably opinionated) LaTeX distribution
> based on TeX Live that is small in size but still functions well in
> most cases. Even if you run into the problem of missing LaTeX
> packages, it should be super clear to you what you need to do. You
> only install LaTeX packages you actually need. The manual should be at
> most two pages long.
>
> Please note that TinyTeX assumes that you are not afraid of using the
> command line... In fact, there is only one single command that you need to
> know: tlmgr. It is probably not too scary.
>
> TinyTeX only provides an installation script that downloads and
> installs TeX Live over the network. It may take a couple of minutes,
> depending on your network speed...
>
> For Linux users, TinyTeX will be installed to $HOME/.TinyTeX and
> symlinks of executables (such as pdflatex) are created under
> $HOME/bin, which should be on the PATH environment variable:
>
> ```
> wget -qO- \  
> "https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/raw/master/tools/install-unx.sh" |
> sh
> ```
>
> > ...
>
> To uninstall TinyTeX, simply delete the folder from your file
> manager/browser, or use command line:
>
> ```
> # Linux tlmgr path remove 
> rm -r "~/.TinyTeX"
> ```
>
> Compare the way to uninstall TinyTeX with the ways to uninstall other LaTeX > distributions, and you may appreciate how much simpler it is to get rid of
> TinyTeX than other LaTeX distributions. That is because TinyTeX is just a
> self-contained folder.

## Edit: @cfr asked how does it work in a multi-user scenario

There are three options, the simple "everyone uses it but only root installs news packages", the complicated "create a tinytex user group and chmod it" and the reasonable "each user may have his local package tree". Questions 7 and 8 on the official [FAQ](https://yihui.name/tinytex/faq/) describe it:

#### 1 - Download and prepare a fully portable distro without root:

```
wget -qO- \
  "https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/raw/master/tools/install-unx.sh" | \
  sh -s - --admin --no-path
```

#### 2 - Set symlinks and permissions as root

```
sudo ~/.TinyTeX/bin/*/tlmgr path add
chown -R root:staff ~/.TinyTeX
chmod -R g+w ~/.TinyTeX
chmod -R g+wx ~/.TinyTeX/bin
```

#### 3 - Each user initializes its own package tree

```
tlmgr init-usertree
```

#### 4 - Users run `tlmgr` using the `--usermode` switch to install whatever package they need

```
tlmgr --usermode install koma-script xcolor
```

Adjusting these commands to specific sysadmin scenarios should be trivial after a couple minutes of pondering.

Questions 9 and 16 of the FAQ deal with Debian-based package managers\repos\PPAs and with macOS respectively, and are worth a read too.

## Second Edit: Just noticed TinyTeX's Hall of Pain...

includes at least three references to the "TeXlive too big for Docker container, MikTeX too esoteric for life" situation: https://yihui.name/tinytex/pain/

A testimonial that mentions files sizes:

> Removed TeX Live from my system (openSUSE): 1.5gb. Installed TinyTeX +
> the dependencies to compile my thesis: 150mb!!!! This is great! —
> [Bruno Rodrigues](https://web.archive.org/web/20180524151233/https://twitter.com/brodriguesco/status/942162790587957248)

Comment: But every user has to do this individually?

Comment: @cfr: No. In the distribution site there are instructions to install for all users on a Linux system - static install, only root can add packages, or each user having its own package tree.

See answer 8 on https://yihui.name/tinytex/faq/

Comment: You might want to clarify that in your answer, since that would be a significant disadvantage for some people. (I guess it doesn't have to be root owned, either. You could do it the way I do for TL with a dedicated user.)

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a rather old post, but if you want to build a docker image with a complete TeX Live installation (vanilla TeX Live from TUG) you can reduce its size to about 1.72 GiB instead of 5 GiB which is quite acceptable depending on your needs. However, this just minimizes the image size and does not do on-the-fly installation, because it has all packages.

Okay, so how does it work? The TeX Live installer gives you the option not to install the documentation and source files which results in a TeX tree that only contains the relevant files for a compilation. I highly doubt that you will look up documentation files in a docker image.

Let's start off with the choice of your image. Unfortunately, you cannot use Alpine this time as TeX Live does not ship certain binaries for Linux/MUSL, e.g. biber. So we can resort to Debian.

Furthermore, you need to install some dependencies before getting started, depending on the tools you want to use:

- JDK for tools like arara
- libncurses for xindy
- some perl libraries for biber and other perl tools
- python-pygments for minted

These are not "expensive" after all. Last but not least you install the vanilla TeX Live with a custom profile:

```
selected_scheme scheme-full
tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 0
tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 0
tlpdbopt_autobackup 0
tlpdbopt_sys_bin /usr/bin
```

That means that you want all package (scheme-full), but do not want any documentation and source files, just the packages. And the last instruction just says that we want our symlinks in /usr/bin, so that we do not have to care about PATH manipulation.

After installing you can call `tlmgr path add` and you will have your binaries symlinked to your PATH. Then you are ready to go.

Full Dockerfile (partially based on [sumankhanal/texlive-2018](https://hub.docker.com/r/sumankhanal/texlive-2018/dockerfile)):

```
FROM debian:sid

ENV TEXLIVE_INSTALL_NO_CONTEXT_CACHE=1 \ 
    NOPERLDOC=1

RUN apt-get update && \ 
  apt-get install -y wget unzip tar \ 
  make fontconfig perl openjdk-8-jre libgetopt-long-descriptive-perl \
  libdigest-perl-md5-perl libncurses5 \ 
  python3-pygments && \ 
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz && \ 
  tar xzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz && rm install-tl-unx.tar.gz && \ 
  cd install-tl* && \ 
  echo "selected_scheme scheme-full" > install.profile && \ 
  echo "tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 0" >> install.profile && \ 
  echo "tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 0" >> install.profile && \
  echo "tlpdbopt_autobackup 0" >> install.profile && \ 
  echo "tlpdbopt_sys_bin /usr/bin" >> install.profile && \
  ./install-tl -profile install.profile && cd .. && rm -rf install-tl*

RUN /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr path add
```

Comment: For anyone using this answer: Since this year (1st April of 2021) a binary for musl comes with TeXLive.

Answer (score 6):

For a CI environment, I would base on one of the Island of TeX texlive images. It is availble at https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive

To choose between `minimal`, `basic`, `small`, `medium`, and `full` etc., please consult [What makes up each TeX Live install-tl scheme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500339/what-makes-up-each-tex-live-install-tl-scheme).

For really minimal, start with `registry.gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive:TL2023-latest-minimal`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

I use

1. texlive-lang-greek
2. texlive-xetex
3. texlive-latex-extra
4. texlive-fonts-extra
   and
5. texlive-math-extra

You can replace the language with english + more if needed,

You can avoid xetex and fonts-extra if you dont use XeLaTeX

But the others I have discovered are really useful to let them "out of the game"

PS: Also I think your question is opinion based and will probably be closed

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Why do you think this question is opinion based? Basically, I'm asking for a name of a package that a) has minimal set of binaries (pdflatex, tlmgr, bibtex/biber, perl, I might be missing something) b) contains a minimal set of LaTeX packages so that at least an empty document would compile. If I understand correctly, everything else will be handled by texliveonfly (barring some esoteric cases, of course).

Comment: I don't know... Probably I missed things... I didn't answer about compilation of "hello world" latex file... I talked about the texlive packages that are common used in more of the cases (That just allows you to compile as much latex projects as possible without installing everything of texlive). If I am off-topic please let me know to delete the answer.

Comment: Comment probably important: Never used latexmk till now!

Comment: Hm, why did you not use `latexmk`? I don't think I saw a better alternative. I find it quite helpful (and many TeX editors are running it under the hood for their build systems).

Comment: Just didn't happen yet. But also I prefer to be independent of unnecessary tools. I can run latex twice when I have bibliography and I want to know that latex has to be runned twice than letting a script closing my eyes and make me know less about the real program (latex)...

Comment: You don't say which distro you use. You don't know what distro the OP uses. So you have no idea if these packages even exist there or, if they do, what they provide.

Answer (score 2):

I come from a project where the documentation guideline simply says

```
apt-get install build-essential python3 python3-pip \
    texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended latexmk
pip3 install sphinx sphinx_rtd_theme
make
```

I kept on doing this and noticing that it pulled in on the order of 1 gigabyte of `-doc` packages which would never get used for anything actually. When you are sitting on the bus and your phone drops to 3G, that means something like 30 minutes of additional build time.

I don't want to investigate the full dependency chain and replace the `texlive-latex-extra` dependency with a long, hand-tuned list of packages which is going to change behind my back without notice.  I don't want to build my own replacement.  I just want to download less.

On Debian, a simple but crude workaround is `equivs`, which allows you to build a small package which does more or less nothing at all. In fact, one of the original motivations for `equivs` was to [allow you to **lie** to `dpkg` that something is already installed](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/install/blocking-deb-dependencies.html) so it doesn't pull it in as a dependency.

Going over the build transcript, I see the following packages which I don't need. I dropped these into an `equivs` package and install that as part of the build.

```
texlive-latex-base-doc         # 45.6M
texlive-fonts-recommended-doc  #  2.7M
texlive-latex-extra-doc        #  364M
texlive-latex-recommended-doc  # 40.6M
texlive-pictures-doc           #  105M
texlive-pstricks-doc           #  238M
```

That's some 796M of packages with pure documentation, and about 60% of the entire volume of dependencies. I'm sure the downloads could be pruned further if you know what you are doing, but this was definitely low-hanging fruit.

My set of `equivs`-built fake packages is available from https://packagecloud.io/tripleee/texlive-no-doc/install and the source is on Github: https://github.com/tripleee/texlive-no-doc-equivs

Answer (score 2):

I use `texlive-full` but remove the docs and the language packs from it. To do so, I don't install the `texlive-full` metapackage, rather all the packages that it installs (minus the docs and language packs). For this, I run this piped command:

```shell
sudo apt-get install $(sudo apt-get --assume-no install texlive-full |
    awk '/The following additional packages will be installed/{f=1;next}
        /Suggested packages/{f=0}
        f { for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
            if ($i !~ /doc$|texlive-lang|latex-cjk/)
                print $i }')
```

Note that `latex-cjk` is the collection of Chinese-Japanese-Korean language/font packs.

This brings down my LaTeX installation **from 6.5GB to merely 3.5GB** (and yet I have all the packages that I will ever need).

After this, I install the language packages separately which I require:

```shell
sudo apt install texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-german
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/shivams/0e62b79aaef345560c11aa1862b7029c

Comment: Your regex doesn't use any of the facilities of `grep -P` so you can drop that option, which is nonstandard. You can combine the regexes into one, or use `grep -v -e 'doc$' -e 'texlive-lang' -e 'latex-cjk'` and I don't think the final `tr` is useful, either. (A better fix still would be to refactor all of this into the Awk script; see also [useless use of `grep`.](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep))

Comment: True @tripleee. I just use `grep` with the `-P` option everywhere out of habit. But you're correct. We can make this solution more standard by using standard grep and maybe even `awk`. Kindly feel free to edit and update the answer.

Comment: I have submitted an edit suggestion to fold all the logic into the Awk script; it actually simplified it rather nicely, too.

Answer (score 2):

Quite some time has passed since I asked this question, and I have yet another approach to add. One can take NixOS as the base distro for the docker (`nixos/nix:latest` is about 170 MB according to docker registry), and then have a very fine-grained control over the schemes and packages to add, albeit at a price of using `nix` [link](https://nixos.org)

Obvious downside of this approach is `nix` - yet another language and ecosystem to learn, and hence a limitation in collaboration and mental load.

An example of my recent "no fancy packages at all" document - it required the following declaration

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenvNoCC.mkDerivation {
  name = "project name";
  buildInputs = [
    gnumake
    graphviz
    (texlive.combine { inherit (texlive) scheme-basic latexmk csquotes metafont float cm-super graphics; })
  ];
  src = pkgs.lib.sources.sourceFilesBySuffices ./. [".tex" "Makefile" ".dot" ".txt" ".nix"];
}
```

TeX-related part of this script boils down to

```
(texlive.combine { inherit (texlive) scheme-basic latexmk csquotes metafont float cm-super graphics; })
```

In my CI runner the `nix-build` downloads additional ~100MB of data, which is ok-ish for my current needs; it means that I have a ~270MB download size. I still think that we can do better=)

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X, you can use [BasicTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html). It is the option recommended for instance by [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html#macos) (they just recommend to install the `collection-fontsrecommended` package on top of it).

Quoting [About BasicTeX-2017](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/BasicTeX.pdf):

> BasicTeX (73 MB) is an installation package for Mac OS X based on TeX Live 2017.  Unlike MacTeX, this package is deliberately small.  Yet it contains all of the standard tools needed to write TeX documents, including TeX, LaTeX, pdfTeX, MetaFont, dvips, MetaPost, and XeTeX.

Apparently, this package is just a wrapper of the standard TeXLive installation script, tuning some paths and setting the installation to the "TeX Live small scheme" option.