# XeLaTeX, xeCJK and Chinese

Tags: xetex, xecjk

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}

This is mainly an English document.

With a smattering of Chinese: 中文

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
The font "SimSun" cannot be found.
```

Am giving up on pdfTeX (was asking [at this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435891/latex-cjk-and-chinese-gives-missing-font-file-cyberb65/435921#435921)).

Am making the jump to XeTeX. Which packages should be installed besides `xeCJK`? And what default fonts are installed with the packages you would recommend?

Comment: Depending on how big your smattering is, you can use the workaround of defining new font families. `\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}` and `\newfontfamily{\C}[Scale=0.85]{Yuanti SC}`(make sure the font is available in your system), with the usage `{\C 这里可以写汉字}` in the body. This is however annoying once you have more than just a few pieces of Chinese text.

Comment: You're just missing Chinese fonts.  Install fonts properly and then check if they are present using `fc-list`.