# LaTex Pipeline to GitLab

Tags: bibtex

Anyone have any pipeline to run on GitLab to generate a `main.pdf` updated?

**Note:** already try some pipelines, but the `\cite`, `\gls` and `\printbibliography` not work.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you share at least your `gitlab-ci.yml` and maybe a minimal working example that works on your computer but not on GitLab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling (La)TeX files automatically with GitLab CI](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459484/compiling-latex-files-automatically-with-gitlab-ci)

Comment: See also https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive/-/wikis/Compiling-LaTeX-documents-with-GitLab-CI.

Comment: Already try some pipelines, for example:
- [Github - Example](https://github.com/aufenthaltsraum/stuff/wiki/Using-GitLab-CI-for-Building-LaTeX)

But when works not generate images, `\cite` and `\gls` and bibliography not work our are blank.