# Use minimum size pdfTeX to output pdf file

Tags: pdftex, tex-core

I want to use `TeX` to build `.pdf` file in my program. But `TeX Live` is too large and I wanna to embed `TeX` in my little program - it means the `TeX` should be as small as it can.

I try to sreach in Google, but they tell me to use `TeX Live` or others. I just want to get a `pdfLeX` which can only build `Plain TeX`, no `tikz`, no helpful package, no help document but just one programme can run - that is enough for me, because I do not want to have part to build pdf is a lot bigger than the main part.

I try to sreach the release bin file of **just** `pdfTeX` but I cannot find any useful but big things like `TeX Live`.

(one more word, I have the idea that use third library to build `.pdf` file but they are not looking good.)

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397174/minimal-texlive-installation

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer , it really looks can work.