# Avoiding bloatware TeX

Tags: installing

In my studium I needed TeX constantly. Consequently, I installed TeXLive for Windows and didn't care much it took half an hour (OK, my computer was 20 years old) to install everyone and his uncle. (So that everything worked and I didn't have to think about it.) But honestly, 150000 files @ 5 GB?

Meanwhile, I have a brand new (only 10 years old :-) PC and, since I will need TeX only casually and surely not with every whistle and bell, I'd prefer a minimalist setup. Is there a possibility to do it "a la mode Python", i.e. only install a core and maybe some common stuff that is needed all the time, and if something special is needed after all, post-install that feature?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397174/minimal-texlive-installation - I'd go with samcarter's answer here (`scheme-basic` is almost certainly what you are after).

Comment: Or use MiKTeX, which starts small and does auto-install

Comment: yes you can install scheme-basic then just install what you need with tlmgr, that is often used for Continuous integration setups. Or use an online server such as overleaf or texlive.net and don't install anything at all

Comment: The issue tends to be that 'just the basics' means very different things to different people; if you want a smaller system but without loosing functionality, consider installing everything but skipping the `doc` and `source` trees, as that cuts down a good portion of the size

Comment: https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bamsmath%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0AYou%20do%20not%20need%20to%20install%20anything.%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D

Comment: [TinyTeX](https://yihui.org/tinytex/)