# Which are the essential differences between LaTeX and ConTeXt?

Tags: context, comparison

I know that **LaTeX** and **ConTeXt** are extensions of **TeX** but each is based in a different philosophy.
Beyond of its *tex engines* (**ConTeXt** works with *LuaTeX* for example) this question is focused to understand the advantages and disadvantages depending its use.

1. Where is better use **LaTeX** or **ConTeXt**?
2. Why **ConTeXt** seems less known?
3. Advantages of use **ConTeXt** instead of **LaTeX** or viceversa

Comment: Circular short anwser: Context is less known because  its disadvantage.  Context disadvantage is that is less known.

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/why-should-i-be-interested-in-context and some of the linked questions?

Comment: Context's main engine is now luametatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ConTeXt mark-IV  or ConTeXt mark-II?

Comment: the newest is called "context lmtx"

Comment: You could take your question replace "LaTeX" with  "French" and "ConTeXt" with "Italian" and "TeX" with "Latin" and post to languagelearning stackexchange. Any answers that you get would apply equally here.